# How can I submit a web form by clicking keyboard button?

Tags: php, javascript

```
<form action="page.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="some_text" />
    <input type="submit" name="some_submit" /
</form>
```

I want to submit this form by pressing defined keyboard button. I wonder how to do it. If it was just an `<a>` element it would be simple - I would just change `window.location` value after handling keypress event. But there is some data to send and I have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

The data will be passed automatically as a result of form.submit()

Answer (score 2):

You can create an event handler for a key press event, then submit the form using its `submit()` method to pass all the form data to the recipient page "page.php".

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), this is trivial:

```
<form id="myForm" action="page.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="some_text" />
    <input type="submit" name="some_submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#myForm").keyDown(function(e){

        if(e.which == 13) // When key pressed is "Enter" key.
            $('#myForm').submit();

    });

</script>
```

Read [Javascript Madness: Keyboard Events](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) for more information on interpreting keyboard events.

Answer (score 1):

Give a name to the form

```
<form name="myform" action="page.php" method="post">
```

After handling key press event do

```
document.myform.submit()
```

which will basically submit the form. If you want to add more parameters to it add those as hidden elements inside form.

Comment: Please don't do that. A standard way would be - `document.forms.myform`

Answer (score 0):

For an example of key press handling, see http://dev.kanngard.net/Permalinks/ID_20050426091851.html - it submits a form if key 13 (Enter) is pressed, but can be modified to any other key.

In general: register a function to be called on KeyDown event, inside the function, check which key was pressed; if needed, submit() your form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in trouble:

```
function action(button) {
if ($('a.'+button+':visible').length > 0) {
    if ($('a.'+button+':visible').attr('class') == button || $('a.'+button+':visible').attr('class') == 'rotate '+button) {
        var adr = $('a.'+button+':visible').attr('href');
        window.location = adr;
    }
    if ($('a.'+button+':visible').attr('class') != button) {
        $('a.'+button+':visible').click();
    }
}
    if ($('input.'+button+':visible').length > 0) {
        $('#form').submit();
    }
}
```

Where variable 'button' is button's classname and #form is form's id. By clicking submit it works normally, but it doesn't work by keyboard event.